# ¿Como leer el valor de un bloque de html en C#?

Tags: c#, html

Necesito pasar un bloque de html que tiene una etiqueta con una ruta de una imagen (este bloque esta guardado en la base de datos), la ruta de la imagen la necesito poner en una funcion de c#.

Ya obtengo el html como un string pero no logro extraer el valor del elemento

```
//Esta es la conexion aqui si muestra el bloque html que viene de la base de datos
cone.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cone;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT encabezado from dbo.cuentas where codigo =  '" + codigoCuentas + "'";

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //reader.Read();

        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;



        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["nombre"]));
            encabezado = reader["encabezado"].ToString();
            prueba.Text = nombre;
            cone.Close();
        }
```

Bloque html que muestra como string

```
<div style="text-align: center;" align="center"><br></div><div style="text-align: center;"
align="center"><img src="/pcaAdmin/Uploads/PCA 3 peq.png"><br></div><hr>
```

Lo que necesito es poner la ruta del img src en este codigo

```
iTextSharp.text.Image logoTims = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("Aqui va la ruta");
```

Comment: la ruta de la imagen esta en la bd??

Comment: el bloque de html esta guardado en la base de datos por lo que yo hago un select y lo muestra, pero muestra todo el bloque con las etiquetas

Comment: pon tu codigo para que podamos ayudarte e intenta ser mas claro que lenguaje estas usando PHP??

Comment: Estoy utilizando c#  voy a poner el codigo en otro comentario para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Y `itextsharp` que tiene que ver con el tema?

Comment: Por cierto, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: que usas mysql, oracle, sql server, mongo, sqllite?? edita tu pregunta con tu código no lo pongas como comentario

Comment: Y por último, si lo que necesitas es "parsear" el html, te recomiendo que uses una librería para ello, por ejemplo [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) o [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/)

Comment: Y a fin de cuentas HTML es un derivado de XML, podrías parsearlo mediante alguna libreria XML y obtener el atributo que necesita, aunque sin  ofender quien fue el idiota que se le ocurrió eso de guardar HTML en la BD

Comment: Voy a probar con HTMLAgilityPack, gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Y la verdad no se quien guardo esto, yo estoy modificando este codigo que ya estaba hecho, porque si tiene partes muy mal hechas.

Comment: Si, solamente la ruta!

Comment: creo que la respuesta esta en el substring @gbianchi si es que lo que va antes del src no cambia...

Comment: @Arturo debes elejir la respuesta que consideres correcta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias probar algo asi...

Como tu string es casi "estatico" o sea que tiene la misma forma, y el div solo tiene una imagen (eso esperamos!), algo asi deberia devolverte lo que estas buscando:

```
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("<img src=") + 10);
s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('"'));
```

donde s es la cadena que tiene tu DIV originalmente. Puede que tengas que ajustar alguno de los indices (lo hice sin probarlo), pero por lo general va a devolverte la cadena que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Si el bloque HTML siempre va a tener la misma estructura, puedes usar expresiones regulares (Regexp) para obtener el valor que necesites. Es un tema complejo pero de gran utilidad para casos en los cuales la estructura siempre tiene la misma forma.

En un regexp puede comparar un texto cualquiera contra un patrón y ver si calza. Si calza, puedes capturar grupos de resultados (los que se indican entre paréntesis). Existen muchos ejemplos [en MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) y [otros sitios](http://regexhero.net/reference/).

Un ejemplo real de una app:

```
        // en la variable content tenemos la página en HTML. El formato es:
        // <tr class="par"><td><a href="/events/sensibles/2014/03/11-1845-28L.S201403.html" target="centro">2014/03/11 15:45:29</a></td><td>53 km al NO de San Pedro de Atacama</td><td>4.0 Ml</td></tr>

        const string pattern =
            "<tr class=\"[^>]*\"><td><a href=\"([^\"]*)\" [^>]*>([^<]*)</a></td><td>([^<]*)</td><td>([^<]*)</td><td>([^<]*)</td><td>([^<]*)</td><td>([^<]*)</td><td>([^<]*)</td><td>([^<]*)</td></tr>";
        var reg = new Regex(pattern);

        Match m = reg.Match(content);

        while (m.Success == true)
        {
            var t = new Temblor(id, rkey);
            DateTime tmp;  
            // capturar fecha y hora del temblor
            if (DateTime.TryParse(m.Groups[3].Value, new CultureInfo("es-CL"),
                    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal,
                    out tmp) == true)
                    t.Time = tmp;
            list.Add(t);
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
```